# Return UserName and ServerName using Get-TSSession

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm writing a PS script that will search a textfile of terminal servers, find disconnected sessions and return the username and server name.

The purpose is to send an email to users with disconnected sessions on a regular basis to try to get them to log off properly. When they don't log off they tend to keep our legacy data entry systems open which increases the incidence of index / table corruption.

The code I have so far is thus:

```
$tsservers = Get-Content .\powershell\terminalservers.txt

foreach ($i in $tsservers){

    #write-output $i

    $Sessions = Get-TSSession -ComputerName $i | where {(($_.state -eq "Disconnected"))} | Select -ExpandProperty UserName
    foreach ($session in $Sessions) {

        $query = "SELECT * from ds_user where ds_sAMAccountName='$session'"
        $user = Get-WmiObject -Query $query -Namespace "root\Directory\LDAP"
        $user.DS_mail
    }
}
```

Using this I can retrieve their UserName and query AD to produce their email. I've tried many many times to work the server property into that code but to no avail.

Edit 1: Ideally I would like to pass in multiple properties (eg: disconnect time, etc).

Comment: Sorry, but for me your question is not so clear. Does this script work ? If no then what is the error, if yes what is the question ?

Comment: Just in case you haven't already considered the auto-logoff [angle](http://serverfault.com/questions/369858/automatically-log-off-idle-terminal-services-users-without-using-idle-session-li)...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Noam. I did indeed consider that. However, the auto-log off would potentially force-close the data entry applications and increase the incidence of data/index corruption. I wish this were not the case as it would be the quickest and easiest solution. Thanks for the suggestion, nonetheless.

Comment: JPBlanc - the script does indeed work. However, I was not able to return (and use) more than a single property at a time. That was the problem being asked which was addressed by Ansgar's solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want to retrieve multiple properties from the session object? I can't test this from here, but I'd probably try something like this:

```
Get-TSSession -ComputerName $i | ? { $_.state -eq "Disconnected" } | % {
  $username   = $_ | select -ExpandProperty UserName
  $server     = $_ | select -ExpandProperty Server
  $disconnect = $_ | select -ExpandProperty DisconnectTime
  ...
}
```

As for retrieving AD user information, it'd be easier if you used the `ActiveDirectory` module:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

...

$user = Get-ADUser -Identity $username -Properties mail
$mail = $user.mail
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the offered solution. It works perfectly! I did want to comment on the ActiveDirectory module portion. This would require an additional module.. whereas my code above already works fine (without the need for additional modules). What would be the benefit of using your code? Is it more performant? Or is it just cleaner / more-readable? Thanks again for the great solution!

Comment: It's just easier to read and to maintain (in case of requirements changes).